# Is there any simple way to copy whole linux with installed packages, config files etc.?

Tags: linux, archlinux, manjaro

I use linux to code on my computer. But there is a necessity to fast copy whole system into my notebook. It wouldn't be problem to install system and packages but... I have really lot of packages installed. Most of them, are configured manually. I don't have enough time to install them manually, would be nice if some program or "magic way" exists to copy whole system easily :) Do you know some?

Answer (score 1):

Boot into a bootable live Linux environment. 
Mount your root partition to this live Linux. 
Now mount a hard disk. 
Run

```
sudo dd if=/address/of/your/root of=/address/of/output/file
```

This will make an image of your root partition. Now in your notebook, make a partition the size of your root, and run live Linux and mount the hard disk. 
Do not mount the to be partition.

Run

```
lsblk
```

And note the name of the to be root partition.

Now run

```
sudo dd if=/address/of/root/image of=/dev/name/of/to/be/root/partition
```

This should write your root into that partition

Configure the grub to detect that partition as an os. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/400886/how-can-i-add-a-new-operating-system-boot-entry-to-the-grub2-menu)

Comment: This has to be done with the root _unmounted_. So, it can/should be done by booting a rescue disk to get a standalone shell.

Comment: Oh, ok. I forgot about the unmounted root thing. Instead of the rescue disk, I prefer a live environment from a bootable pd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync` to back up and install packages to a new installation. Please search first before asking here, as archlinux forums are very rich with information. The link you need is this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/full_system_backup_with_rsync

Keep in mind that this is not something that is safe, the hardware is much different and many problems can occur. I would suggest a new installation from scratch

Comment: `rsync` doesn't really work to copy a live system onto another (running, obviously) live system.

Comment: I dont think he is talking about copying into a live system. Also it is a terrible idea to copy a system like this.

Comment: If you want `rsync` to work, both the sending and the receiving end need to be "life". It's not intended to copy over systems.